# Vaadin abnormal memory consumption (memoryLeak?)

Tags: memory-leaks, client, vaadin, callable

for a project I'm working on (Spring Boot 2.7.9 + Vaadin 14.9.7) I'm experiencing a strange heap memory usage.
Attached to this post you can find the first objects by top memory usage in my application.
I see there is a big usage from PendingJavaScriptInvocation and UIInternals$JavaScriptInvocation.
The application is accessed by 500 users but only 30-40 concurrently, and I've put some ClientCallable functions to accomplish ARIA accessibility (on row grid buttons) as per the tutorial that can be found here https://cookbook.vaadin.com/aria-label-to-components.

Could you please give some advise on what to put the eye on to understand a so big heap usage ?

[image: Heap usage]

Comment: That's a known issue, but it should have been fixed in 14.9.7. If you're able to reproduce it still with 14.9.7, please file an issue on https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues

Comment: issue https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/16572 submitted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a memory leak in DataCommunicator producing too many of PendingJavaScriptInvocations: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/14435 . That ticket is fixed in Vaadin 14.8.18, however you're using Vaadin 14.9.7 and thus this might be something new. Could you please report the issue at https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues ?

It could be important to check which component produced all of those pending invocations. You can perhaps try to place a breakpoint into the PendingJavaScriptInvocations constructor; the breakpoint won't stop the JVM but would only log the caller. Alternatively, PendingJavaScriptInvocations.owner may reference the culprit component, you could try to discover that in the heap dump.

Comment: I've submitted issue  github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/16572